# how to override core controller method

Tags: nopcommerce

I want to use core controller method which is "product" action method and non action `prepareProductDetailMethod` in my plugin but I want to only override this method in my plugin
not implement again in my plugin

So.How to call core controller method?

Please give me steps as well as example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use it,because all that methods are protected,if you want it from another controller in nopcommerce then you can do it but you need to declare this protected methods as a public, but from plugin you can declare them public, so just copy that method in your plugin.